# Outline at cover

Tags: rendering, freestyle, lineart

Is it possible to have outline generated only at places when two or more objects are covering each other? Not intersecting, just being partially behind each other.
I am working a character with flat colour shading, but I need to add distinction to arms and hands, whenever hands are touching or are in front of the face.
I have tried freestyle, lineart modifier and the new geometry node outline addon from Tradigital, but so far I was not successful.
The best way I can describe what I am looking for is inverted "external contour" setting in freestyle.

[image: inverted external contour]